# Custom Robotframework Library needs to be called as MyModule.MyModule when in PIP

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

As I'm finishing up development of my Library/Listener I've come to the stage where I'm packaging up my files for PIP delivery. Now I'm running into an issue where I have to load my custom Robot library as `MyLibrary.MyLibrary` in a robot file instead of the desired singular `MyLibrary`.

```
Library    MyLibrary.MyLibrary    some input string
```

The corresponding python project structure is:

```
robotframework-mylib/
├── MyLibrary/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── MyLibrary.py
│   ├── MyListener.py
│   └──utils.py
├── LICENSE.txt
├── README.rst
└── setup.py
```

The distribution I create using the regular `python setup.py sdist` command. Then I install it using `pip install robotframework-mylib-1.0.0.tar.gz`.

To my knowledge two consecutive names is condensed to a singular one, but perhaps this is dependent on something in `__init__.py` or  `setup.py` but then this detail eludes me. Help and constructive criticism or questions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying was a pure Python problem and had nothing to do with Robot Framework.

In the `__init__.py` the required libraries were mentioned in the `__all__` section, but were not imported. When I added the import the main module was accessible again through it's singular name.